# clickable dropdown invisible DIV

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make a clickable dropdown menu similar to the one on google where you click your username and a menu appears and you can log out. I built this menu using a hidden div and then made it visible via onClick and javascript to change the CSS.  However if you highlight the entire page, the invisible div is shown and I dont like the way that looks.  Google's doesnt show.  Is there another way to get the same effect without using a hidden div? thanks

EDIT: when i said "highlight," i meant if you crtl+a

Comment: @keoki the only place ive seen it is if you log into a google account and go to www.google.com  its in the top right bar

Answer (score 2):

Use display:none; instead of whatever you're using.

```
<div class="test"></div>

.test {
display:none;
}
```

Comment: i got it but what do i change display: none to in order to show the div?

Comment: You could change it to     display:block; or something, or maybe just have it remove the display:none;. I have no idea what would be the best solution for you without seeing what you are doing exactly.

Comment: @user780483 : Richard is completely right here. You should not use the 'visibility' property, as it is a pain when it comes to cross-browser coding (maybe this has been fixed since I last worked with it, though I doubt it). You should code your JS to switch between `display: none;` and `display: block;` (or inline or whatever other display method is your default).

Answer (score 1):

An example: http://jsfiddle.net/TMS88/